# 404 Page for Multi-lingual Page

Tags: localization, 404, 404-page

For my multi-lingual-Page (de + en) I've made a 404.html-File in my templates-Folder with a language-changer for html-content-output like

```
{% if craft.app.language == 'de-CH' %}<p>Hallo</p> {% else %} <p>Hello</p> {% endif %}
```

When I open the 404-pages local (localhost/404 and localhost/en/404) it works. Also when I open them in live with direct url ([www.example.ch/404](http://www.example.ch/404) and [www.example.ch/en/404](http://www.example.ch/en/404)) everything works fine.

But when I will open a wrong URL like "www.example.ch/tesxt" (correct URL: [www.example.ch/test](http://www.example.ch/test)) I get a **HTTP 404 – Not Found – yii\web\NotFoundHttpException Template not found: tesxt**

Settings:

- I only have one index.php
- I only have one 404.html
- in general.php: **'devMode' => false,**
- the 404.html is directly in templates-Folder (src>templates>404.html)
- installed Plugins: DigitalOcean Spaces Volume, Freeform, Redactor (I think these will not disturb the 404 page)
- Craft Version: 3.5.17
- PHP-Version: 7.3.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why. But I did the Redactor updates in Craft, uploaded the new vendor folder to the hosting provider and now it works.